# Does the Sacred Kin barbarian's Supernatural Fury feature replace the Rage feature entirely?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, rage

This question is about the **Supernatural Fury** feature of the *Path of the Sacred Kin* barbarian subclass from [*Xanathar's Lost Notes to Everything Else*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/228484/Xanathars-Lost-Notes-to-Everything-Else) (a third-party product by the DMs Guild Adepts).

The Supernatural Fury feature states:

> At 3rd level, you can focus on the magic in your
>   blood, allowing you to concentrate your rage into the ancient magic of
>   your bloodline and enter a Supernatural Fury. You gain the ability to
>   cast and concentrate on spells, even while raging, at the expense of
>   your physical resistances.
>
> When you enter your Supernatural Fury and you aren’t wearing heavy
>   armor, the following benefits replace the benefits of the Rage
>   feature:
>
> - You gain a bonus to your AC equal to your Strength modifier (minimum of +1).
> - You have advantage on Constitution checks and saving throws made to maintain concentration on a spell.
> - You have resistance to magical damage and are immune to the damage type you chose from your Ancestral Origin.
>
> Your Supernatural Fury lasts for 1 minute. It ends early if you're
>   knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven’t attacked a
>   hostile creature, cast a spell, or taken damage since your last turn.
>   You can end your Supernatural Fury on your turn as a bonus action.

Does this mean the Sacred Kin barbarian can choose between entering a "regular" rage and a Supernatural Fury? Or can he (from Level 3 on) only gain the benefits from Supernatural Fury, because it completely replaces the "old" rage he used on Level 1 and 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, Rage is only replaced when you enter the Supernatural Fury

The way this is worded, the Rage feature is not removed upon reaching level 3. Instead the feature is disabled while in the Supernatural Fury. This means that you could enter a "regular rage" but these features are disabled while in the alternate state.

### This shows that the wording is probably flawed

Because of the earlier bit in the feature: "You gain the ability to cast and concentrate on spells, even while raging", you could also cast spells while in a "regular rage." This is almost certainly not the intent.

Comment: I don't know that that wording would let you just cast spells while in a regular rage with no downsides, at best such a reading would still take away your physical resistances, which given the upsides listed below that part it would be sub-optimal if possible.

Comment: The feature doesn't explain how to enter a Supernatural Fury either. Do I need to be raging? Do I need to use an action? I wouldn't use this *Path of the Sacred Kin*: if they didn't put enough effort to word the **core** feature properly, what else did they botch?